# AngularJS: IE Access Denied displaying PDF

Tags: angularjs, pdf, blob

While trying to display a pdf blob on IE, I receive Access is denied error.

html file

```
<object ng-show="{{content}}" data="{{content}}" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

js file

```
$http.post('/api',{}, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
                    .success(function (response) {
                        var file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                        var fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                        $scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileUrl);
                    });
```

When using embed instead, acrobat pdf viewer is unable to view the temporary file.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Mike Sorry for such a late response. I was unable to find any solutions or workarounds for IE.